# PHP only IF ternary statement

Tags: php

I haven't been able to find the answer to this but it seems that a PHP if only statement would be really handy. Most of the time I have used an if statement inside of html it does not require the else and the else usually ends up being just a blank string anyway.

So my question is, is there anything similar to the below I can do?

```
<a class="<?php ($url == '/login') ? echo 'active'; ?>" href="/login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo an empty string if the ternary is false

```
<a class="<?php echo ($url == '/login') ? 'active' : '' ?>" href="/login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use traditional if statement

```
<a class="<?php  if($url == '/login') { echo 'active'; } ?>" href="/login">Login</a>
```